# Obfuscation and Intellitrace VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, obfuscation

Is it possible to use Intellitrace on obfuscated C# code(or any .net code for that matter) in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, probably, useful, simple, not so much.  Intellitrace may not crash right away, but the entire point of obfuscation is that even if you see all of the code, and what it's doing, you still won't be able to *understand* it.

Comment: You bring up an excellent point. Obfuscation and clarity really are competing and opposite goals.